# simplex method tableau

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, game-theory

If I have the matrix:

x1 x2 s1 s2 s3 z

1 4 1 0 0 0 | 12

2 5 0 1 0 0 | 2

1 3 0 0 0 1 | 4

### ----------------

-2 -1 0 0 0 1 | 0

Then, where x1 is the row of 1, 2, 1....x2 is the row of 4, 5, 4....etc where z = 0,0, 0
and

I'm trying to find the maximum _____ when x1 =  **, x2 = _**, and s1 = 11, s2=0, s3=3

I tried to pivot it based upon the most negative but lost in the algebra

Comment: If you have any questions about the answer feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options to solve this problem.

**First Option**

It seems you know the (optimal) values of the slack variables. You can use this information and 2 of the 3 constraints to calculate the optimal solution. I take the constraints 2 and 3.

$2x_1+ 5x_2  +s_2= 2$

$1x_1 +3x_2 +s_3 = 4$

Inserting the values for $s_1$ and $s_2$

$2x_1+ 5x_2 + 0= 2 \quad \Rightarrow x_1=-2.5x_2+1$

$1x_1 +3x_2 +3 = 4\quad \Rightarrow x_1+3x_2=1$

Insterting the term for $x_1$ into the second equation.

$-2.5x_2+1+3x_2=1 \Rightarrow 0.5x_2=0 \Rightarrow x_2=0.$

Thus $x_1=-2.5\cdot 0 +1=1$

**Second option**

If you do not know the values of the slack variables then you have to apply the simplex algorithm. The initial tableau is

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline x_1&x_2& s_1& s_2&s_3&RHS \\  \hline 1&4&1&0&0&12 \\ \hline \color{red}2&5&0&1&0&2 \\ \hline 1&3&0&0&1&4 \\ \hline -2 & -1 &0&0&0&0 \\ \hline \end{array}$

The pivot column is the first column, because $|-2|$ is larger than $|-1|$. The pivot row is the second one, because $min\left(\frac{12}{1},\frac{2}{2},\frac{4}{1} \right)=\frac{2}{2}$

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline x_1&x_2& s_1& s_2&s_3&RHS \\  \hline 0&3/2&1&-1/2&0&11 \\ \hline 1&5/2&0&1/2&0&1 \\ \hline 0&1/2&0&-1/2&1&3 \\ \hline 0&4&0&1&0&2 \\ \hline \end{array}$

All values of $x_i$ are non-negative. No more transformation is needed. The optimal solution is $(x_1^*,x_2^*,s_1^*,s_2^*,s_3^*)=(1,0,11,0,3)$